# What sound formats mod_rtmp supports?

Tags: rtmp, freeswitch, codecs

Does `mod_rtmp` (freeswitch module) supports all sound formats FLV does? Or some limitations exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as much as I can guess from a glance [here](https://github.com/FreeSWITCH/FreeSWITCH/blob/master/src/mod/endpoints/mod_rtmp/mod_rtmp.c#L90), Speex is preferred (and probably it's the only one supported?)

Comment: Thanks, you are nearly obviously right. But another question then: how can they transmit 16 kHz Speex if FLV AUDIODATA does not support it in turn?

Comment: I don't know, I'm not a Flash specialist :)